# Make unique types from basic types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to give class objects unique id types, even though they're all strings.  I tried using `type` and I tried deriving from a base class with unique subclass names.

See the following example.  Neither `type` nor `extends` allows me to instruct the compiler to treat these as unique types.  I can still pass a HumanId to a function expecting an AnimalId and visa versa.

I get that they're object compatible, and that from the underlying JavaScript perspective, this makes total sense.  In fact, if I add a unique member to AnimalId, I get the error I expect:

**`Argument of type 'HumanId' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnimalId'.`**

Is there a good approach with TypeScript to make unique type aliases for basic types?

```
// type HumanId = string;
// type AnimalId = string;

class id {
    constructor(public value: string) { }
    toString(): string { return this.value;}
}
class HumanId extends id { };
class AnimalId extends id { };

function humanTest(id: HumanId): void {

}

function animalTest(id: AnimalId): void {

}

let h: HumanId = new HumanId("1");
let a: AnimalId = new AnimalId("2");

animalTest(h);
```

Comment: A longer article about this issue:

https://codemix.com/opaque-types-in-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, the types are structurally compatible. The only way to make them unique is to add unique properties to them.

If you only want to compiler to differentiate between the two, you can just add dummy unique members which make no runtime difference:

```
class HumanId extends id {
  private _humanId: HumanId; // Could be anything as long as it is unique from the other class
}
class AnimalId extends id {
  private _animalId: AnimalId;
}
```

Comment: Yup.  Thanks for the confirmation that I wasn't missing a language feature.  I think it would be nice to be able to declare `type HumanId = unique string`.  Some way to take advantage of the compile time checking for basic types to be used for specific purposes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I went with the briefest one-line syntax I could, and did: `class HumanId extends BaseId { humanId }`

Comment: If all you want is type checking, perhaps you could introduce HumanId and AnimalId as types by using a .d.ts declaration file?

Comment: Just to expand on this,  the proposed approach is only one of several others. There is a whole section on this kind of problem called Nominal typing in the TypeScript Deep Dive book: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html

Answer (score 15):

I came across this question, but my use case had a minor twist: I wanted to introducing a unique type for `number`. Think of an API where you have e.g. `hours: number`, `minutes: number`, `seconds: number`, etc. but you want the type system to enforce correct usage of all units.

The [blog post](https://codemix.com/opaque-types-in-javascript/) mentioned by @Evert is a great resource in that regard. The idea is to create an intersection type with some dummy that is never actually used. Creating new unique types can be abstracted away by a generic helper type. Illustrating on the example:

```
// Generic definition somewhere in utils
type Distinct<T, DistinctName> = T & { __TYPE__: DistinctName };

// Possible usages
type Hours = Distinct<number, "Hours">;
type Minutes = Distinct<number, "Minutes">;
type Seconds = Distinct<number, "Seconds">;

function validateHours(x: number): Hours | undefined {
  if (x >= 0 && x <= 23) return x as Hours;
}
function validateMinutes(x: number): Minutes | undefined {
  if (x >= 0 && x <= 59) return x as Minutes;
}
function validateSeconds(x: number): Seconds | undefined {
  if (x >= 0 && x <= 59) return x as Seconds;
}
```

Now a function `f(h: Hours, m: Minutes, s: Seconds)` cannot be called with just any `number`, but ensures full type safety. Also note that the solution has no memory/runtime overhead.

In practice this approach works well for me, because these "distinct" types can be used implicitly in places where `number` is required. Explicit conversion via e.g. `as Hour` is only necessary the other way around. A minor drawback is that expressions like `hours += 1` need to be replaced by `hours = (hours + 1) as Hours`. As demonstrated in the blog post, the benefits can often outweigh the slightly more explicit syntax though.

Side note: I have called my generic type `Distinct` because the name feels more natural to me, and this is how the feature is called in the [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-distinct-type) programming language.

Answer (score 3):

In the ["TypeScript Deep Dive" GitBook](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping#using-enums), there's a more succinct usage of `enum` to distinguish types:

> *Enums in TypeScript offer a certain level of nominal typing. Two enum types aren't equal if they differ by name. We can use this fact to provide nominal typing for types that are otherwise structurally compatible.*

Applying the approach their to my original example, I get the following TypeScript which indeed does not let me call `animalTest` on a "human".  :)

```
enum HumanBrand { _ = '' };
enum AnimalBrand { _ = '' };

declare type HumanId = string & HumanBrand;
declare type AnimalId = string & AnimalBrand;

const makeId = <T extends string>(id:string):T => { return id as T; };

function humanTest(id: HumanId): void {
}

function animalTest(id: AnimalId): void {
}

let h: HumanId = '1' as HumanId;
let a: AnimalId = makeId<AnimalId>("2");

animalTest(h); // Argument of type 'HumanBrand' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnimalBrand'.
```

The `_ = ''` entry (or some other placeholder) is required.

Comment: Note that this is supported with the library [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) as `Opaque`.

Comment: Link is broken. New link: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping

Answer (score 1):

If you want these data types to be serializable in JSON for use in APIs or database structures, they need to remain string base types.  There are two ways to do this.

**(1) Implement ID types as string literals**

Since string literals are strings, TypeScript mostly does the right thing.  For your humans and animal examples, you could create the following string literal types and functions to safely create/coerce these types.

```
const setOfExclusiveIdsAlreadyCreated = new Set<string>();
const setOfExclusivePrefixesAlreadyCreated = new Set<string>();
const createMutuallyExclusiveId = <ID_TYPE extends string>(idType: ID_TYPE, idPrefix: string = "") => {
  // Ensure we never create two supposedly mutually-exclusive IDs with the same type
  // (which would, then, not actually be exclusive).
  if (setOfExclusiveIdsAlreadyCreated.has(idType)) {
    throw Error("Each type of ID should have a unique ID type");
  }
  // If setting a prefix, make sure that same prefix hasn't been used by
  // another type.
  setOfExclusiveIdsAlreadyCreated.add(idType);
  if (idPrefix && idPrefix.length > 0) {
    if (setOfExclusivePrefixesAlreadyCreated.has(idPrefix)) {
      throw Error("If specifying a prefix for an ID, each Id should have a unique prefix.");
    }
    setOfExclusiveIdsAlreadyCreated.add(idPrefix);
  }
  return (idToCoerce?: string) =>
    (typeof(idToCoerce) === "string") ?
      // If a string was provided, coerce it to this type
      idToCoerce as ID_TYPE :
      // If no string was provided, create a new one.  A real implementation
      // should use a longer, better random string
      (idPrefix + ":" + Math.random().toString()) as ID_TYPE;
}

//
// Create our human type and animal types
//

// The human type will appear to typescript to always be the literal "[[[Human]]]"
const HumanId = createMutuallyExclusiveId("[[[HumanId]]]", "human");
type HumanId = ReturnType<typeof HumanId>;
// The animal type will appear to typescript to always be the literal "[[[Animal]]]"
const AnimalId = createMutuallyExclusiveId("[[[AnimalId]]]", "animal");
type AnimalId = ReturnType<typeof AnimalId>;

const firstHumanId: HumanId = HumanId("Adam");
const randomlyGeneratedHumanId = HumanId();
const firstAnimalId = AnimalId("Snake");

// You can copy human types from one to the other
const copyOfAHumanId: HumanId = firstHumanId;
const anotherCopyOfAHumanId: HumanId = randomlyGeneratedHumanId;

// You CANNOT assign a human type to an animal type.
const animalId: AnimalId = firstHumanId; // type error

// You can pass an animal to a function that takes animals.
( (animal: AnimalId) => { console.log("The animal is " + animal) } )(firstAnimalId);

// You CANNOT pass a human to a function that takes animals.
( (animal: AnimalId) => { console.log("The animal is " + animal) } )(firstHumanId); // type error


interface Animal { animalId: AnimalId, makeSound: () => void };

const poodleId = AnimalId("poodle");
const animals: {[key in AnimalId]: Animal} = {
  [poodleId]: {
    animalId: poodleId,
    makeSound: () => { console.log("yip!"); }
  }
};
```

**(2) Implement ID types as enums**

```
// The human type will appear to typescript to be an enum
enum HumanIdType { idMayOnlyRepresentHuman = "---HumanId---" };
// Since enums are both types and consts that allow you to
// enumerate the options, we only want the type part, we
// export only the type.
export type HumanId = HumanIdType;

// Do the same for animals
enum AnimalIdType { idMayOnlyRepresentAnimal = "---AnimalId---" };
export type AnimalId = AnimalIdType;

const firstHumanId = "Adam" as HumanId;
const firstAnimalId = "Snake" as AnimalId;

// You can copy human types from one to the other
const copyOfAHumanId: HumanId = firstHumanId;

// You CANNOT assign a human type to an animal type.
const animalId: AnimalId = firstHumanId; // type error

// You can pass an animal to a function that takes animals.
( (animal: AnimalId) => { console.log("The animal is " + animal) } )(firstAnimalId);

// You CANNOT pass a human to a function that takes animals.
( (animal: AnimalId) => { console.log("The animal is " + animal) } )(firstHumanId); // type error


interface Animal { animalId: AnimalId, makeSound: () => void };

const poodleId = "poodle" as AnimalId;
const animals: {[key in AnimalId]: Animal} = {
  [poodleId]: {
    animalId: poodleId,
    makeSound: () => { console.log("yip!"); }
  }
};

// In order for JSON encoding/decoding to just work,
// it's important that TypeScript considers enums
// of this form (those with only one field that i
// represented as a string) as basic strings.
const animalIdsAreAlsoStrings: string = poodleId;
```

**Considerations for both implementation styles**

You'll need to avoid typing objects used as maps like this:

```
const animalIdToAnimalMap: {[key: AnimalId]: Animal} = {};
```

and instead like do this:

```
const animalIdToAnimalMap: {[key in AnimalId]?: Animal} = {}
```

Still, some typings won't work perfectly.  For instance, if you use Object.entries(animalIdToAnimalMap), the keys will be strings and not AnimalId (which would be the type of keyof typeof animalIdToAnimalMap).

Hopefully TypeScript offer mutually-exclusive Ids in the future and improve the default typings for functions like Object.entries.  Until then, I hope this still helps.  These approaches sure helped me avoid a number of bugs where I would have otherwise passed ids in the wrong order or confused ids of different types.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea to explore. Rather than inheritance, you can define a unique Id type through generics:

```
class Id<Entity> {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  equals(id: Id<Entity>) {
    return this.value === id.value;
  }

  public readonly value;
  // This member exists for the sole purpose of making
  // one Id class structurally different to another
  private readonly _: Entity;  
}


class Animal {
  id: Id<Animal>;
  growl() {}
}

class Human {
  id: Id<Human>;
  makeCoffee() {}
}

const animal = new Animal();
animal.id = new Id<Animal>("3");

const human = new Human();
// This triggers a compilation error.
human.id = animal.id;

human.id = new Id<Human>("3");
// Another compilation error
const humanIsAnimal = human.id.equals(animal.id);

// Demonstrating compatibility
const animal2 = new Animal();
animal2.id = animal.id;
const animalsMatch = animal2.id.equals(animal.id);
```

Comment: This is helpful if your ID is only going to exist in memory and that are not serialized.  The primary reason to use string IDs is to refer to objects that are not always local, and so that need identifiers that are unique across different threads/processes/machines.  You can't reconstitute class-based identifiers automatically via JSON decoding. 
 The beauty of basic types is that they are JSON-encodable.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet mentioned, there's a purely type-based way to do this without `as`:

```js
type HumanId = Special<string, "HumanId">
type AnimalId = Special<string, "AnimalId">

let humanId: HumanId = "foobar" // success
let animalId: AnimalId = "foobar" // success

animalId = humanId // type error
humanId = animalId // type error
```

No casting required! Here's the solution:

```js
interface Specializing<TypeName> {
  _type?: TypeName
}

export type Special<T, TypeName> = T & Specializing<TypeName>
```

Credit for this excellent proposal goes to one [Drew Colthorp](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/). Note that you *can* force your way past the type constraint by generalizing and then re-specializing:

```js
let foo: HumanId = "something"
let bar: AnimalId = "something"
let intermediary: string = bar
foo = intermediary  // succeeds
```

...but as long as you use `HumanId` and `AnimalId` instead of `string` you should be good.

In contrast, "branding," whereby you include a unique dummy value in the object's type, requires casting. So does the `Distinct` type proposed by bluenote10. By the way, the terms "opaque type" and "nominal type" are useful when doing searches on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

> Developing on @bluenote10 example

### This version could be slightly better

```ts
interface Distinct<Name> {
  __DISTINCT__: Name
}

type GroupId = string & Distinct<'GroupId'>
```

Hover type info popup:

```ts
type GroupId = string & Distinct<"GroupId">
```

Error message:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'GroupId'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Distinct<"GroupId">'
```

### Than this one

```ts
type Distinct<T, Name> = T & { __DISTINCT__: Name }

type GroupId = Distinct<string, 'GroupValue'>
```

Hover type info popup:

```ts
type GroupId = string & {
  __DISTINCT__: "GroupValue";
}
```

Error message:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'GroupId'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ __DISTINCT__: "GroupValue"; }'
```

### Because it is

- more robust
- easier to add
- nicer type description and error message

> Typescript 4.8.4