# Typescript with units

Tags: typescript

I'm refactoring some javascript functions dealing in both `Celsius` and `Kelvin` values, non-thermal values are also involved but I'll use Temperature for this example.

I would like for typescript to log a warning here.  The return value `f` is `Kelvin` being passed into an argument that explicitly takes a `Celsius` value.

```js
type Celsius = number
type Kelvin = number

function f():Kelvin {
    return -220
}
function toKelvin(t:Celsius):Kelvin {
    return t - ABSOLUTE_ZERO
}
toKelvin(f())
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create an opaque type. You may find this Stack Overflow Q&A and the article mentioned in the comments and answers usefull:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113119/make-unique-types-from-basic-types-in-typescript
- https://codemix.com/opaque-types-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

[Dominic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7997640/dominic-egginton) pointed me to just what I was looking for.

```js
enum KelvinType { _ = 0 };
declare type Kelvin = number & KelvinType;
enum CelsiusType { _ = 1 };
declare type Celsius = number & CelsiusType;

function toCelsius(temp: Kelvin): Celsius {
    return temp + ABSOLUTE_ZERO
}
function toKelvin(temp: Celsius): Kelvin {
    return temp - ABSOLUTE_ZERO
}

function myFunc(temp: Celsius) {}
let value = 220;
let cTemp = toCelsius(value) // ok
let kTemp = toKelvin(value) // ok
toKelvin(kTemp) // nah
myFunc(kTemp) // nah
myFunc(cTemp) // ok
```